# Prettier doesn't work for CSS

Tags: css, format, prettier

I just implemented ESLint and Prettier in my project.
Linting of JavaScript files works perfectly.
However, for CSS files, things like adding missing semicolon don't work.
Isn't it that Prettier should support CSS too?

Has any one used Prettier to format CSS?

Comment: have you try prettire ext. in vscode ??

Comment: Can you include the content of your `.prettierrc` file or other configuration if you are using one?

Comment: I just checked and prettier was able to format my css and correctly add missing semicolons.

Comment: I pushed a small example to Github:  https://github.com/itsthomas/TinTin-5
In the project ESLint, Prettier and pre-commit are implemented. And  "editor.formatOnSave": true, is activated in VSCode settings to format and lint each time a file is saved.

Comment: If you download and check my example, you will see that the Prettier is not working for the CSS files.

Answer (score 0):

According to prettier repository it supports:

> javascript · flow · typescript · css · scss · less · jsx · vue ·
> graphql · json · markdown · yaml

And I have been use it with VSCode and indeed format a CSS file.

If you are using ESLint, [integrating Prettier](https://prettier.io/docs/en/eslint.html) to your workflow is straightforward.

There are two different ways you might want to integrate Prettier into ESLint. You may enable either one separately, or both.

Happy Coding.

Comment: Are you also using ESLint? Is it possible to share your settings and rules?

Comment: Hmm, this is exactly what I've done. But still no luck with CSS semicolons or quotations. This is the result: https://github.com/itsthomas/TinTin-5